# Как научиться грамотно писать?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый день! Меня зовут Полина, мне 16, и уже 11 лет я живу в Португалии.
Каждый день я говорю на русском языке, но читать и писать практически не умею.
Я давно уже хочу научиться грамотно писать. С чего мне начать?

Comment: Серж, исправьте: неплохо пишЕте.

Comment: Забавно, если с Вами считать, у меня было четыре знакомых из Португалии, одна настоящая португалка Дебора - и вот третья(!) уже Полина. )))  Это я Вас так разговорить пытаюсь, но чистая правда). ?7=Кстати, а в чатах или скайпе вы по-русски общаетесь? Получается?

Comment: А вы неплохо пишете.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полина, этот текст вопроса Вы писали? Если да, то очень неплохо. Если Вы говорите так же, то ничего и не надо. Я не знаю, надо ли Вам какие-то практические пособия изучать. Они все-таки не на таких как Вы ориентированы. Вам если что и нужно, то это практика. Чтобы писать, надо просто больше писать. И читать, конечно. Попробуйте написать о себе побольше. Или о Португалии. О чем-то Вам знакомом. Как попали туда, что дальше собираетесь делать, с кем разговариваете на русском...  Будет это рассказ - еще лучше. А мы проверим - и поймем Ваш общий уровень.

Да, и давайте решим сразу, Вам надо общую грамотность подтягивать (орфографию, пунктуацию, синтаксис) или Вы хотите прежде всего научиться красиво, литературно, излагать свои мысли?

Comment: Прежде всего я хочу по благодарить вас за то что вы мне ответили. На самым дели я лишь розговаривою на русском с мамой и подругой, а в основным я постоянно говорю на португальском.

Comment: Не стоит пока. Тем более, что я по свое привычке насажал массу опечаток. Сейчас править буду)))  Давайте к делу.--- Ну вот, исправил, что увидел. Так какую цель Вы себе ставите: научиться писать красиво, литературно? Или для начала просто правильно с точки зрения правописания?

Comment: Пока я вижу, что Вы насажали ошибок. Хотите буду править? Вот Ваш исправленный текст: *Прежде всего я хочу **побл**агодарить вас за то**_,_** что вы мне ответили. На самым дел**е** я лишь р**a**зговарив**а**ю на русском с мамой и подругой, а в основн**о**м я постоянно говорю на португальском.* Мое мнение, что вам самостоятельно, без преподавателя будет трудно такие пробелы ликвидировать.

Comment: На самым дели через 2 года я собираюсь поступить в университет в России, и именно и за этого я хочу научиться грамотно писать.

Comment: Я буду не против

Comment: Ну вот, в комментарии выше - я исправил текст. С университетом - понятно.  Мой совет - зайдите на грамоту newforum.gramota.ru - и расскажите там о себе -  как я выше писал. Там есть люди, которые знают много и о преподавании, и о российских университетах.  Для Вас будет больше толку, чем тут спорить о методике преподавания.

Answer (score 2):

Интересная ситуация.

1) А если попробовать для начала так: составьте или возьмите самый простой текст небольшого объема на португальском (английском) языке и онлайн получите его перевод на русском языке.

2) Теперь перед вами запись текста известного Вам содержания на русском языке. Попробуйте его прочитать.

3) Потом сравните запись конкретных слов и их произношение, которые различаются между собой, например: коробка - к(а)ро(п)ка. Так вы познакомитесь с фонетическим чередованием звуков в русском языке, например: О без ударения произносится как А, согласные перед другими согласными оглушаются и т.д.

4) Теперь отложите текст в сторону и запишите его на русском языке по памяти. Так же работайте с другими текстами, постепенно усложняя их содержание.

5) Знание фонетического чередование позволит Вам понять, **какие буквы можно писать по слуху, а какие нельзя, так как они требуют проверки**. А что такое проверка? В русском языке мы как бы пишем не слова, а морфемы (приставки, корни, суффиксы, окончания), проверяя буквенный состав этих морфем.

Так, в слове "коробка" мы должны проверить две буквы корня (О и Б): корОбка - кОроб, короБка - короБочка.

Comment: Спасибо вам, я обязательно попробую.

Answer (score 1):

> На самым дели через 2 года я собираюсь поступить в университет в России, и именно и за этого я хочу научиться грамотно писать.

Полина, если Вы планируете поступать как иностранный гражданин - не волнуйтесь, возьмут. Тест Вы сдадите, писать не заставят.

Преподаватель вуза

Comment: Спасибо. От меня. )))

Answer (score 0):

Еще предложения:

- найти книги, переведенные с португальского на русский, и читать одновременно на 2-ух языках. Потом писать рассказы о прочитанном.
- смотреть фильмы и мультфильмы с титрами на русском (но не народные сказки). Потом записывать содержание.
- общаться в чатах и в Skype по-русски. Кстати, на этом сайте есть чаты.